# Take column value into a column MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

Working with Python 3 and Pandas 1, I have a data frame like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'param1'],
                   ['a', 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 'param2'],
                   ['b', 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 'param1'],
                   ['b', 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 'param2'],
                   ['c', 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 'param1'],
                   ['c', 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 'param2']],
                  columns=['object', 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 'parameter']).set_index('object')
```

```
        2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006 parameter
object                                              
a          1     2     3     4     5     6    param1
a          7     8     9    10    11    12    param2
b         13    14    15    16    17    18    param1
b         19    20    21    22    23    24    param2
c         25    26    27    28    29    30    param1
c         31    32    33    34    35    36    param2
```

and would like it to look like this:

```
year       2001            2002            2003            2004            2005            2006    
parameter  param1  param2  param1  param2  param1  param2  param1  param2  param1  param2  param1  param2
object                            
a          1       7       2       8       3       9       4       10      5       11      6       12
b          13      19      14      20      15      21      16      22      17      23      18      24
c          25      31      26      32      27      33      28      34      29      35      30      36
```

where `year` and `parameter` are levels of a MultiIndex in the columns, such that and element's 'co-ordinate' is

```
(object, (year, parameter))
```

note that the values of the `parameter` column are used to create the MultiIndex level `parameter`.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `append=True` for `MultiIndex in index`, set columns name by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and then [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index('parameter', append=True).rename_axis('year', axis=1).unstack()
print (df)
year        2001          2002          2003          2004          2005  \
parameter param1 param2 param1 param2 param1 param2 param1 param2 param1   
object                                                                     
a              1      7      2      8      3      9      4     10      5   
b             13     19     14     20     15     21     16     22     17   
c             25     31     26     32     27     33     28     34     29   

year               2006         
parameter param2 param1 param2  
object                          
a             11      6     12  
b             23     18     24  
c             35     30     36
```

Comment: Exactly it. Thanks @jezrael